# Click on parent then event on child

Tags: jquery

When I click on .letitre, I want to simulate a click in the child element .mybutton

**HTML :**

```
<div class="letitre">
    <div class="mybutton">Button</div>
</div>
<div class="letitre">
    <div class="mybutton">Button</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

This function is working (the click is well simulated) BUT it will always click on the first .mybutton and not in the child .mybutton where .letitre is the parent.

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("click", ".letitre",function(){
        $(".mybutton").click();
    });
});
```

Si I tried this but it's not working (no click at all)

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("click", ".letitre",function(){
        var button = $(this).find(".mybutton");
        $(button).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: `button` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the button and click it, and you need to delegate both if you delegate one

Also it is imperative to stop the propagation or you will loop

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".letitre", function(){
    $(this).find(".mybutton").click();
  });
  $(document).on("click",".mybutton", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // make sure the click stops here
    console.log($(this).text())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="letitre">
    <div class="mybutton">Button</div>
</div>
<div class="letitre">
    <div class="mybutton">Button2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working, just don't forget the . to mybutton (find)

Comment: @Youstart - I had to add a stopPropagation

Comment: Using vanilla Javascript there was no looping problem, see my answer. A click on `div.mybutton` won't trigger the listener if you properly check the event target.

Comment: @connexo  - that is highly unlikely. I am sure jQuery would be coded one element at a time and I am pretty sure the button would have its own event handler somewhere else than letitre

Answer (score 1):

Just another question that is just as easy, if not easier, to solve using no jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if (target.matches('.letitre')) {
    target.childNodes[1].click();
    console.log("clicked child:");
  }
  // just so you see .mybutton gets clicked
  if (target.matches('.mybutton')) {
      console.log(".mybutton received the click!");
  }
})
```

```css
.mybutton { color: #a00; }
```

```html
<div class="letitre">Outside
    <div class="mybutton">Button</div>
</div>
<div class="letitre">Outside
    <div class="mybutton">Button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And why no looping? I added this to yours: `document.querySelectorAll(".mybutton").forEach(but => but.addEventListener("click",function() {console.log(this.textContent)}))`